# Does an aperture value exist, where a lens creates a brighter image than the real view?

Tags: aperture, brightness, science, physics

So (without limitations of the viewfinder for example) looking through the viewfinder 
creates a brighter image than normal view would be.

The lens would then work like a funnel(collects light from large area) or magnifying glass(creates bright spot as well).

I know the difference of t-stop vs f-stop and also know that f/1.0 is not a magical aperture value or something like that btw.

Answer (score 5):

Well, sort of. Think about the sun shining through a lens — it's immediately apparent that the focused spot of light is brighter than the unfocused.

However, the catch is that your "real view" also goes through a lens which focuses the light: your eye. So, in a sense, the real comparison is simply "Is there a lens which is brighter than the human eye?" — and the human eye's aperture is somewhere on the slower edge of fast lenses. No matter how you measure, it's certainly slower than a f/1.4 lens.

But, I think party what you're asking is if a lens can effectively act as an all-optical night-vision device. The catch is that the eye isn't *much* slower than that f/1.4 lens... probably not much more than 2 stops. That means that the fastest lens possible doesn't really gain that much.

*Overall*, at least in the context of photography, I think this turns out to be less exciting than it might seem at first. That's because the effect of a an aperture faster than the human eye is only part of the overall equation. We can also make sensors that have higher gain than even the night-adjusted human eye, but most crucially, we can use long exposure to integrate over a much longer time than our own vision does in low light. So, overall, it's really, really easy to produce an image which has an exposure much higher than the scene appears naturally.

Comment: If you're viewing an image projected onto a focusing screen (like when using an SLR) then the aperture of your eye is irrelevant to whether what's seen on the focus screen is brighter than the view with the naked eye, since your eye aperture applies a constant brightening factor to both. If you're talking about holding a lens up to your eye, than that's an optical system with two apertures and is therefore only as fast as the smallest aperture.

Comment: @MattGrum   That is more or less what I meant indeed.           So putting an f/0.5 lens (just an example) to your eye will not result in a brighter image than without the lens?

Comment: @FW. It's not possible without some reduction in field of view / change of focal length. Otherwise you'd be able to screw something on the front of an f/2.0 lens to make it an f/1.4 lens. The Metabones Speed Booster only works because it screws on the back of the lens.

Comment: @MattGrum: As you alluded to, it depends on FoV. When I hold my 16X60 binoculars to my eyes, the stars and other objects in the night sky are *much brighter* than they are to my naked eye. My 4.5" reflecting telescope does this even more so. This is because they are taking the light falling on a much larger surface area than the pupil of my eye and concentrating that light onto the pupil of my eye. With a telephoto lens, the *effective* aperture is all that needs to be larger than the recording medium or eye pupil to concentrate more light per cm^2 than is falling on the objective lens.

Comment: In theory, it is possible to place additional elements on the front of a lens. If the addition has a larger surface area than the original objective by a factor greater than the additional magnification needed to concentrate the light collected through the aperture, it would result in a net brightness gain. It just isn't practical or cost effective to do this externally, but that is the essence of what a classical telephoto lens design is.

Comment: Just a quick note...I'm not sure I'd equate sensor gain with eye sensitivity. Gain amplifies what little light the sensor collects, and in the average case the photodiode itself is only around 45% efficient (Q.E. of 45%, so only 45% of the light reaching the photodiode actually frees an electron). Out of the total amount of light reaching the sensor, 30-40% is filtered by the CFA, so the 45% Q.E. is 45% of 35%...~16% overall Q.E.! The rods in our eyes are sensitive to a SINGLE PHOTON, or ~100% Q.E...so the eye is a far more sensitive device in low light than an image sensor.

Comment: A good test of this fact is trying to do astrophotography with a mirrorless camera that has an EVF. The EVF uses the sensor's sensitivity, and outside of the brightest stars, all you can really see is sensor noise. Use a DSLR with an optical viewfinder, however, and the sensitivity of your eye can see dozens, hundreds, maybe even thousands of stars with enough adjustment time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68020/discussion-on-answer-by-mattdm-does-an-aperture-value-exist-where-a-lens-create).

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to disagree with the other answers - we'll maybe just question them.

Take your magnifying idea. You are not making the sun brighter! You are just focusing the caught by the lens into a small point, making it appear brighter.
Light gets "lost" through every surface it passes through or bounces off of. You may change the appearance of it's luminosity, but certainly not enhance it.

This is not a scientific argument from my part, merely an opinion..

Comment: It should be a scientific one - specifically the 1st law of thermodynamics.  You can't get more energy out of a system than you put in...  :)

Comment: Light CAN be lost at each material interface. That does not necessarily mean it IS lost. Light is generally lost at disjoint material interfaces due to the different refractive indexes, which tends to cause some light to reflect. Multicoating helps cancel out reflected light, which prevents a loss in contrast, but not necessarily a loss in light overall. However, recently, both Canon and Nikon have started using nanocotings. With a nanocoating, the material interface is "softened", such that reflection never actually occurs because there is no hard interface. So, 99.95% of light is preserved!

Comment: (Well, preserved at each interface...total light lost these days is less than 0.1%). The primary sources of light loss in a digital camera are: 1-The IR Cut and AA filters, 2-The CFA, 3-Photodiode Q.E. For any given pixel in a bayer-type sensor, as little as 10% of the light actually reaches the photodiode and frees an electron. :O

Comment: "More light in the same place" is pretty much the definition of brighter. :)

Comment: @JamesSnell: You are not creating light to make the image brighter, you are redirecting it. By focusing almost all of the light falling on a large objective onto a much smaller image plane or exit pupil, you are concentrating all of that light on one small spot, at the expense of the surrounding area that receives none of the light it otherwise would if the optical system (in this case a lens) were not redirecting it. There is the same amount of energy in the system, it has just been redirected.

Comment: @Theo: With the magnifying glass the sun isn't brighter, but the amount of light falling on the bright spot *is* brighter by the same net amount as the amount of it that is not falling on the shadow created by the magnifying lens (less the amount reflected by the lens). Place a tube between the magnifier and the focal plane to keep out diffused light and you can clearly see that the lens casts a shadow over the areas not receiving the concentrated light. The more efficient the lens is at focusing the light to the center bright spot, the darker the shadow will be.

Answer (score 3):

This is physically impossible. Without active amplification, the [luminance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance) of the image can not be more than the luminance of the subject. Otherwise you would be violating the second law of thermodynamics. If you try to focus the sun rays on a black body, it can get really hot, but not hotter than the surface of the sun itself. For a mathematical proof, read this about the [conservation of etendue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue#Conservation_of_etendue), and remember that luminance is just luminous flux per unit of etendue.

**Edit:** The brightness *can* be optically increased if you use the word “brightness” in the astronomical sense: the “brightness” of a star is the [illuminance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminance) it delivers to Earth. This is a definition that makes good sense for *pointlike* sources, like stars.

However, when talking about photography (other than astrophotography), we usually deal with *extended* scenes rather than *pointlike* sources. Then the proper notion of “brightness” is the *luminance* rather than the *illuminance*. And the luminance cannot be increased.

Comment: Sure it can. Luminance is a measure of the intensity of light *per unit area*. If we collect light from a large area and redirect it to a much smaller area the luminance will be increased. We're not increasing the total number of photons, but we are increasing the number of *photons per mm²*.

Comment: @MichaelClark: No. What you are defining is called _illuminance_ And of course you can increase it by concentrating the light into a smaller area. What I am talking about is _luminance_, which is the photometric quantity most relevant to the question. And no, you cannot increase it unless you use some sort of amplification (like, e.g., a video camera and a monitor). Please, see the Wikipedia articles I linked to.

Comment: Extended scenes can be brightened in exactly the same way that point sources can. That's how something such as the Metabones Speedbooster works: light from a larger area is concentrated on a smaller area.

Comment: @MichaelClark: – sigh – The Speedbooster increases the **illuminance** on the sensor, not the **luminance**. Please stop mixing up the two notions, otherwise any discussion on the topic is pointless.

Comment: The question above makes no mention of *luminance* or *illuminance*. What it does ask is if looking through the viewfinder can be *perceived by the human eye* as brighter than the original scene. Your answer introduced an insistence of restricting the question to that of *luminance* rather than *illuminance*, which by your own definition in your first comment above is what the question actually asks. Shoot me for saying *luminance* above when I should have used *illuminance*, but **the question as asked is clearly about illuminance, not luminance.**

Comment: @MichaelClark: The “brightness perceived by the human eye” is a complex topic: it is subjective, not quantifiable, affected by afterimages, dark adaptation, etc... However, for an extended object, the _measurable_ quantity that most closely correlates with the perceived brightness is the _luminance_, not the _illuminance_. I'm not inventing anything new: this is old and _quite solidly established_ science. You can ask Google, or [physics.se](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) if you want more details.

Comment: The question is primarily about *perception*. You can't just dismiss that as too complex and substitute what you would like the question to be and answer that instead.

Comment: @MichaelClark: I do not dismiss the question. On the contrary: I state that there exists a measurable photometric quantity that closely correlates to the perception of “brightness” of an extended scene, namely, the _luminance_. And it is not that I “would like” it to be so. It is standard textbook knowledge: the notion of luminance as a objective measurement of brightness is one of the _most fundamental concepts_ of photometry. If you have problems with that (I don't blame you, it _is_ subtle), you should sort this out first. This may help: [Fire From Moonlight](https://what-if.xkcd.com/145/).

Comment: You're still refusing to recognize that the original question asked above relates more to *illuminance* than to *luminance*. What you say about *luminance* is correct. **But it isn't what the question is asking.** If one looks at the moon with the naked eye the number of photons passing through the eye's pupils per second are fewer than the number of photons passing through the eye's pupils per second when viewing the moon through the viewfinder with a very wide aperture lens. That's what the question is basically asking.

Comment: Those photons are not being created *ex nihilo*, they're being redirected from where they otherwise would fall on the parts of the face of the observer surrounding the eyes. The skin on the face surrounding the eyes is receiving *less* light (in an amount equal to the increase where it is being redirected - less the amount reflected and absorbed by the optical system) than if the optical system were not redirecting that energy into a smaller area.

Comment: The same is true of a more evenly illuminated extended scene. The light collected by the larger objective lens and concentrated at the exit pupil is not longer falling on the face and the resulting shadow makes the amount of light falling on the face behind the lens' objective less than it would be were it not being redirected to a smaller area.

Comment: @MichaelClark: Your statement “the original question asked above relates more to _illuminance_ than to _luminance_” is unfounded. The question is about “brightness” and, for an extended scene, _luminance_ (and not _illuminance_) happens to be the right way to measure “brightness”. Your comments demonstrate that you have no clue on photometry but, more importantly, that **you are not willing to learn**. Discussing with you is a waste of time. Live happy with your misconceptions. I give up.

Comment: The question is about brightness **as seen through the viewfinder**!

Comment: @MichaelClark: Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, yes. The human eye reportedly only opens as far as f/3.2, and there are many lenses faster than this. The Canon 50mm f/1.0 for example was marketed as being "faster than the human eye", although the f/3.2 figure suggests it shares that award with most prime lenses.

The biggest obstacle is designing a reflex mirror, pentaprism and focus screen that will accept the full light cone from a fast lens without clipping it and effectively narrowing the aperture. Consumer DSLR laser cut screens cut off at about f/2.5. Old fashioned ground glass screens don't have this limitation but aren't as bright generally.

**note** there's a crucial difference between looking through the viewfinder of an SLR and holding a lens up to the eye. In the first case you are viewing an image projected onto a screen, whereas in the second case you are forming a multi-lens system that includes the human eye.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible since the eye samples light from a relatively small surface area where as a lens samples light from a much larger area.  The bigger problem is the huge discrepancy between the sensitivity of the eye and the sensitivity of sensors.  I can already take photos with my Canon 5D Mark iii with fairly short shutters (sub 1/3 second, sometimes even 1/10 second) that have more color and contrast than what I actually see in the scene with my naked eye and I have really good night vision.

As far as something to help the naked eye, the biggest problem would be the necessary size of the front element I think.  To double the amount of light, the lens would have to be very large since you are also going to have light lost in the lens system itself.